# Possibilities of the IWizard interface

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-generation, wizard, project-template

I've played around with Visual Studio Project Templates and found them useful so far. 
Now I've found some material on Wizards and the [IWizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.templatewizard.iwizard%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) interface.

The [first basic steps](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15268/How-to-Create-Your-own-Visual-Studio-Wizard) are fairly easy to comprehend and seem very useful, but now I'd like to explore what else the IWizard interface has to offer, other than mere Text replacement. I can imagine a few use cases for the ShouldAddProjectItem method, but what - for example - if I want the user to be able to pick database tables and have the wizard generate model, mapping and CRUD-dao code (I already have an assembly for that tedious task)?

Can anyone give me links or hints on facilities of the interface?

Comment: That's a lot of feedback already =)

Comment: I'm auto-building created application in `ProjectFinishedGenerating` method using DTE. It makes XAML files active, not asking to build the project.

Comment: could you explain that a bit?

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to make CRUD, DAO, etc... I'll suggest you to check T4 Templates and, if you want more power.
2. Combine T4 with [Dev Art's Entity Developer](http://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/)
3. Put it all inside a IWizard

Let me explain it a little bit more...

You'll need to develop some T4 Template integrated with Entity Developer (to apply either Entity Framework's or NHibernate's metadata) or standalone, in  order to create as many CRUD-Dao-Service-DTO like classes you need.

Then, with the T4, you can create a new project, add it as long as a Entity Developer empty model, export it as project template, and make a IWizard with a custom dialog as show in the example you referenced.

In this IWizard, you ask for the Connection String, then you make text replacement with IWizard replacement and... you're done! User makes a "Update Model from Database" and the Entities are done.

I hope this hints are enough to start!